# How to find error value on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

While using csv files from excel and read it with pandas data frame, got 1 value that's has symbol such as 2$3.74836730957 while it has to be 243.74836730957 (it seems mistook 4 with $). is there anyways that I could find such as values that I mention before and change it into `NaN` values on Data Frame?

CSV file:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_numeric` in order to report boolean values that denote whether a particular column has only numerical values. In order to check all columns you can do

```
df.apply(lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').notnull().all())
```

And the output would look like:

```
A    True
B    False
C    True
D    False
...
dtype: bool
```

---

Now if you want to know which specific row(s) are not numerical you can use [`np.isreal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isreal.html):

```
df.applymap(np.isreal)

          A     B      C     D
item
r1      True  True  True  True
r2      True  True  True  True 
r3      True  True  True   False
...
```

Comment: Thankyou. i'll use the code for determine the error values.